# Pattern mixes in with value on input

Tags: html, input, razor

**Can someone explain to me why this code:**

```
<input id="ContactEmail" class="txtbox txtboxlarge" type="text" placeholder="Email asd..." value="" pattern="^[^@@]+@@[^@@]+\.[^@@]+$" required asp-for="AnalysisInput.ContactEmail" />
```

**Renders this HTML:**

```
<input id="ContactEmail" class="txtbox txtboxlarge" type="text" placeholder="Email asd..." value="" pattern=" value=" ^[^@="" [^@="" ]+$"="" required="" name="AnalysisInput.ContactEmail">
```

As you can see the value mixes in with the pattern :|
I have the same input field on another different razor page, and there it renders perfectly fine..

```
<input id="CompanyInvoiceEmail" class="txtbox txtboxlarge" type="text" placeholder="Email til fakturering..." value="" pattern="^[^@@]+@@[^@@]+\.[^@@]+$" required asp-for="CreateSupplierFrontend.InvoiceEmail" />
```

**RENDERS AS**

```
<input id="CompanyInvoiceEmail" class="txtbox txtboxlarge" type="text" placeholder="Email til fakturering..." value="" pattern="^[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+$" required="" name="CreateSupplierFrontend.InvoiceEmail">
```

I tried copying the input field and checking if they match, which they do.

Comment: It seems to be the  asp-for="AnalysisInput.ContactEmail"  that does it. 
As soon as I remove that, it renders correctly.
However, that still doesn't explain why it works on another page, and not this one...

Comment: If I instead change asp-for   to  name=""   in the HTML, it renders correctly.   I don't know why this is required on this page - so hope someone can shed some light on it, just to clarify ;)